# How can I manipulate the client-side appearance of websites on Android/iOS using JavaScript for a mobile game?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile-development

I have an idea for a game which consists of adding elements on certain web pages in a player's browser on Android/iOS. It has to be their native browser and not a custom one for this game, as the idea is to play whenever you enter a certain site when doing normal browsing.

A very rough outline when a user enters a site would be:

1. Check with a server if the website is part of the game
2. If so, add a textbox or an image to the website using javascript

Is this possible to do? Would it be allowed on app stores? If so, what tools/frameworks would be the best option?

Comment: I don't think you can add any behavior to the native browser. This would be a major security issue because every app could do whatever it wanted within the browser.

Comment: If you don't have access to those websites it's not possible. If you own them, you can do whatever you want but only with those websites you own.

Answer (score 0):

The title leads to suspicious behavior. 
To manipulate a website, you need to modify the server side code, which means hacking / cracking a website,  kinda illegal...

At description:

> adding elements on certain web pages in a player's browser on
>   Android/iOS

that means you aren't manipulating the website, but the client's browser only!
That is possible on android rooted phones, but depends on each browser, actually you aren't manipulating the website.

I highly doubt would be allowed at App Store, at Play Store is easier.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, that is indeed what I meant and I've changed the title. If it's impossible to change the client-side code, is it possible to make a transparent layer on top of the browser which could act as a similar solution?

Comment: not really, interacting with other apps it is prohibited also. Just think about it! Yo want to view Stackoverflow.com on your phone and  if would ever install any of my app it would be a porn site... or something else, what is not related.